# Create child processes to print lines from a file but last line disappeared without extra \n

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

I have a problem when writing a C program to print out the lines of a file. Suppose the file has 5 lines, it should create 5 child processes. Each child process reads a line from the file and prints the respective line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define BUFSIZE 256
#define ITR 1e6

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) exit(1);
    pid_t pid;
    char buffer[BUFSIZE] = { 0 };     // create buffer 
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r"); // read file into *fp
    while (fgets(buffer, BUFSIZE, fp)) {
        pid = fork(); 
        if (pid == 0) {
            for (int j = 0; j < ITR; j++);
            printf("%s\n", buffer);
            _exit(0);               // exit child 
        } 
    }
    wait(NULL);                     // wait for child to finish
    return 0;
}
```

The original file is

```
Child 1 reads this line\n
Child 3 reads this line\n
Child 2 reads this line\n
Child 4 reads this line\n
```

The output is listed below.

```
Child 1 reads this line\n
\n
Child 2 reads this line\n
\n
Child 3 reads this line\n
\n
Child 4 reads this line\n
\n
```

However I don't want the extra `\n` between two lines. So I modified `printf("%s\n", buffer);` to `printf("%s", buffer);` so there would be only 1 `\n` as in the original file. But the output turns to be

```
Child 1 reads this line
Child 2 reads this line
Child 3 reads this line
```

The last line which should be `Child 4 reads this line` didn't print out as I expected. Does anyone know why this would happen?

Comment: Add a `fflush(stdout);` after the child's `printf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some problems you should investigate:

- you should use `exit(0)` or `return 0` instead of `_exit(0)`: the non-standard function `_exit()`, equivalent to `_Exit()` on linux,  might not properly flush standard stream buffers:

  > **7.22.4.5 The _Exit function**
  > *Whether open streams with unwritten buffered data are flushed, open streams are closed, or temporary files are removed is implementation-defined.*
- the loop `for (int j = 0; j < ITR; j++);` has no side effect, so it is highly likely optimised out by the compiler.
- `stdout` to a terminal is line buffered by default, so `printf("%s\n", buffer)` issues 2 separate system calls to flush the output to the system:

  1. one for the buffer contents that ends with a newline and
  2. on for the `\n` in the format string.

  These system calls might be interlaced between the different children processes. You should change the buffering method with `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, BUFSIZ, _IOFBF)` prior to the first output operation, in this case before the `printf` is sufficient.

Here is a modified version you can try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define BUFSIZE 256
#define ITR 1e6

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) exit(1);
    pid_t pid;
    char buffer[BUFSIZE] = { 0 };     // create buffer 
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r"); // read file into *fp
    int lineno = 1;
    while (fp && fgets(buffer, BUFSIZE, fp)) {
        pid = fork(); 
        if (pid == 0) {
            setvbuf(stdout, NULL, BUFSIZ, _IOFBF);
            printf("%d: %s\n", lineno, buffer);
            exit(0);               // exit child 
        }
        lineno++;
    }
    wait(NULL);                     // wait for child to finish
    return 0;
}
```

On my system, each line is output with an extra newline but not necessarily in the same order as the input file.